# Can I use findall to know which item of a list has the smallest price?

Tags: list, prolog

I'm implementing an algorithm that puts all the paths between two cities in a list. This list saves the path and the total price that taking that path costs. The list looks like this:

```
[(12, [A,B,C,D]), (15, [B,C,D,E]), ... ]
```

After I have all the paths in this list I want to know which one of them is the least expensive. I know I could do this myself, but I was wondering if there was any way I could use `findall/3` to accomplish this task.

Comment: You can. You need a predicate to traverse the path, and another predicate to calculate the cost parallelly in `:Goal` of `findall(+Template, :Goal, -Bag)`. `+Template` is your city list, and `-Bag` is your collected results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a asserted data predicate similar to:

```
insert_data :-
    assert(cities(CITYA,3)), assert(cities(CITYB,2)).
```

And the what you might want to do is something like:

```
my_query(City, L) :-findall(Name, (cities(City,Weight),
    setup(City1,Weight1),
    setup(City2,Weight2), 
    Weight2-Weight1),L),!.
```